# PhoneGap + Jquery Mobile Nothing Shown

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile with phonegap and angular JS. When include jquery Mobile, then nothing shown in android mobile and when remove jquery mobile evry thing work but cannot pick jquery-mobile.css. i think there is jquery confliction.

all files are includes as

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-carousel.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lodash.underscore.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <!-- NVD3 re-usable charting library (based on D3) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nvd3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nvd3/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <!--- Imager Assets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/jquery.vintage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/jquery.cropper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/spoon.js"></script>



    <!--- Images Assets -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Whats wrong with this.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i seem problem with jquery mobile. but don't know how can solve it.

Comment: This is usually due to Javascript errors during app initialization. You need to get more information from your app's logging.

Comment: Lot of errors shown but i cannot understand these that's why cannot get idea what's wrong and solve the problem.

Comment: Understood, but you need to share the errors with SO so others can help you.

Comment: @sherb

these errors are shown:

E/AudioMTKHardware(137): setParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=off"

E/NativeCrypto(4102): ssl=0x621ff388 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6162dab0 arg=0x0

 E/KeyguardHostView(531): Error when trying to bind default AppWidget: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a appwidget provider: ComponentInfo{/}

11-02 15:51:43.080: E/stp_dump(143): table == NULL || table->table == NULL

Answer (score 0):

use the phonegap developer app http://app.phonegap.com/, and connect the application using that app, the app have console, so that you can see exactly what wrong.

but as per my experience with PhoneGap+AngularJs+JQueryMobile, we have to choose either AngularJS or JqueryMobile both are not working together as expected. other wise choose appropriate modules of JqueryMobile and use them.